# how can I extract courses title/school/description from a website (such as Udacity)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
summaries = soup.find_all("li", class_="") #using "card-list_catalogCardListItem__aUQtx" for class_ resulted in 0 case
print('Number of Courses:', len(summaries)) #this finds 225 case 

summaries[7].select_one("li").get_text().strip() #output: 'AI for Business Leaders'
summaries[7].select_one("a").get_text().strip() #output:'Artificial Intelligence'

courses = []
for summary in summaries:
    title = summary.select_one("a").get_text().strip()
    school = summary.select_one("li").get_text().strip()
    courses.append((title, school))
#to get all the summaries text extraction will result in "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"
```

[image: Udacity Website html snippet]

For educational purposes, in order to extract

*1)all Udacity courses*
*2)Under what schools*
*3)Short Description*

I attempted to use the above code using "`find_all`". My manual search suggests there are 264 courses on the page. I initially used '`find_all("li", class_="card-list_catalogCardListItem__aUQtx")`'tag which results in 0 finding. The closest number was 225 when I left `class_` empty, just to test. However, this at the end will result in `AttributeError` when I intend to use the 'for loop' to extract all the courses. This is perhaps because not all the summaries found are readable "`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`".

My question: how can I make this work? (since `find_all` tags findings seem to fail)

Comment: You are reading the static source code from the page.  But perhaps the course list is dynamically generated by javascript and not included in the static source.  To check, `print(soup)` to see what your source looks like.  If you want to scrape a javascript-oriented websites, check https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Answer (score 1):

The page is loaded dynamically via sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://www.udacity.com/data/catalog.json?v=%223cd8649e%22
```

You can send a request to that link to receive all the data, where you can access the keys/values as a Python dictionary (`dict`):

```
import requests


url = "https://www.udacity.com/data/catalog.json?v=%223cd8649e%22"
response = requests.get(url).json()

for data in response:
    course = data["payload"]
    if "shortSummary" in course:
        print("{:<50} {:<60} {:<50}".format(course["school"], course["title"], course["shortSummary"]))
```

Output (truncated):

```
School of Data Science                             Data Engineer                                                Data Engineering is the foundation for the new world of Big Data. Enroll now to build production-ready data infrastructure, an essential skill for advancing your data career.
School of Data Science                             Data Scientist                                               Build effective machine learning models, run data pipelines, build recommendation systems, and deploy solutions to the cloud with industry-aligned projects.
School of Data Science                             Data Analyst                                                 Use Python, SQL, and statistics to uncover insights, communicate critical findings, and create data-driven solutions.
School of Data Science                             Programming for Data Science with Python                     Learn the fundamental programming tools for data professionals: Python, SQL, the Terminal and Git.
School of Autonomous Systems                       C++                                                          Get hands-on experience by building five real-world projects.
School of Product Management                       Product Manager                                              Envision and execute the development of industry-defining products, and learn how to successfully bring them to market.
```

Using `{:<50} {:<60} {:<50}` will align the text to the left with the amount specified.

Comment: Thanks @MendelG. Certainly useful alternative. Would you please explain how you obtained the URL? if I am to do as such for other websites.

Comment: @N.S. In your browser, open your Developer Tools (usually by press F12) goto 'Network' and view the Network calls being made

Comment: Thanks @MendelG, I attempted by selecting JS in the Network section and loading the page. None of the JS generated gives me the one you have. I appreciate if you elaborate more.

Comment: @N.S. in the Network section, select "XHR",  not "JS"